# How to glue multiple steps directories to a cucumber test in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have a Cucumber scenario whose steps are defined in multiple Step files, as opposed to only having only one. If I decide to run the test using Intellij I go to `run/debug configurations` menu and the form provides a field named `glue` which enables me to specify the steps package.

So far I was able to run the scenarios that have all steps defined in the same Steps file, but I was unable to figure out how to do it for the scenarios that require multiple steps files located in different packages. I've tried a csv approach but without success. Does anyone know what I am missing? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which Cucumber implementation and version are you using?

Comment: cucumber-java-4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M.P. Korstanje's answer provides very useful tips but not for this specific case. What worked for me was:

1. Specify the parent package as opposed to several distinct sub-packages (e.g. use only `com.example` instead of both `com.example.steps1, com.example.steps2`) in the `Glue` field
2. Select the correct module in the `Use classpath of module` field.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are few ways to configure the glue paths with Cucumber.

As a `cucumber.properties` file in the root package (usually `src/test/resources/cucumber.properties`):

```
cucumber.glue=com.example.steps1,com.example.steps2
```

Via the command line

```
--glue com.example.steps1 --glue com.example.steps2
```

Or with the `@CucumberOptions` annotation.

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue ={"com.example.steps1", "com.example.steps2"})
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

When using IDEA you have to separate the glue packages with a new line or space (not a comma!).

```
com.example.steps1
com.example.steps2
```

And if you are on a recent version of Cucumber (6+) you don't have to provide the glue at all. Cucumber will search the class path by default.